# How to plot 10th power range in gnuplot or xmgrace?

Tags: gnuplot, xmgrace

I am using the following data set:

```
x = 10, 20, 50, 100;
y = 1.2e-5, 3.5e-8, 6.8e-14, 2.5e-20;
```

If I plot x:y in gnuplot or xmgrace, the y points in the plots are indistinguishable (particularly the last three ones).

Is there is any trick to customize the y axis so that smooth and distinguishable points are obtained?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sensible thing to do here would be plotting your data using a logarithmic scale on the y axis. With `gnuplot`, if your `data.txt` is

```
10 1.2e-5    
20 3.5e-8  
50 6.8e-14  
100 2.5e-20
```

You can try in the gnuplot prompt

```
gnuplot> set logscale y 
gnuplot> p [0:120][1e-25:1e-3] "data.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

In xmgrace you can set the log scale either from the command line:

```
xmgrace -log y myfile.dat
```

or with the GUI by opening the `Plot` -> `Axis properties...` panel, selecting the `Y axis` from the `Edit` dropdown and setting the `Scale` dropdown to `Logarithmic`. Close the panel by clicking on `Accept` and your `Y` axis will be shown with a log scale.

Comment: @SomnathBhowmick that's great to know! FYI, note that you can accept only one answer. By clicking on the grey checkmark you changed the accepted answer from the one written by Davide Fiocco to mine. If you think an answer is useful you can upvote it (on top of accepting it, if you will).

Comment: both you and Davide Fiocco's suggestion worked. But I cannot upvote as my reputation is less than 15. Sorry :(